# Elevate zoom jquery plugin Zoomfactor

Tags: jquery-plugins, zooming

I am currently using elevate zoom
I want to be able to change the zoomfactor on the images. Any ideas on how to do this. The website seems to not have any documentation on this. 
Any other jquery zoom plugin with zoomfactor that would be better than elevate zoom.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the scrollZoom: "true" setting you can you zoom in further on an image using your mouse scroll wheel.

There is an example on the elevate zoom page here under the mousewheel zoom section : http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

I'd also like to be able to just choose or set the zoom factor *without* enabling the scrollZoom functionality, but as far as I can tell it is not possible.

Comment: That seems to be the best way to do it. I tried making some Javascript changes  that resizes the image inside the  zoom container. It seems to be working but it's a very ugly hack. I think using the mouse zoom is a better idea.

Comment: Yes I started to go down a similar path but decided it was getting too hacky. I also ended up making the actual dimensions of the "large" zoom image bigger, and that at least gives the feeling of a higher level of detail.

@Manatarms if you think this is acceptable, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer?